# Is there elegant way to write type alias in polymorphic lambda

Tags: c++, type-alias

Consider the following code:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>

    auto cref_lambda = [] (const auto& il){
        using T= typename decltype(il)::value_type;   
    };

    auto cval_lambda = [] (const auto il){
        using T=typename decltype(il)::value_type;
    };

    int main(){
    std::initializer_list<int> il;
    cref_lambda(il);
    cval_lambda(il);
    }
```

cref_lambda does not compile because we are trying to :: into a reference.

I am aware of the workarounds(using `std::remove_reference_t` or just using `decltype(*il.begin());`) but I wonder if there is a better idiom to use here.

Comment: What means better?

Comment: I would like to use value_type since I feel it is clearer for somebody reading code for the first time. In a sense: Ah it is just an alias for the value_type of initializer list.

Comment: And what's wrong with `std::remove_reference_t`? Seems it does not hardly decrease readability. In case if you'd like to make it shorter you may use `decay_t`.

Comment: Your use-case is a bit contrived.  Since your lambda doesn't capture anything you could just use a free template function, like `void cref(std::initializer_list<T> const &il) { /* use T and il */ }`.  This way you get `T = value_type` for free.

Comment: @HenriMenke now that when I think about it I think you are probably right... Feel free to move your comment in A and I will accept it if nothing clever comes up in another A.

Answer (score 1):

The way to resolve your problem at hand is to add `std::decay_t` to the `decltype` instruction.  From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay):

> Applies lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer implicit conversions to the type T, removes cv-qualifiers, and defines the resulting type as the member typedef type.

Most importantly, it acts as the identity for a type which is not qualified according to any of the above annotations.  Hence it is safe to write

```
using T = typename std::decay_t<decltype(il)>::value_type;
```

to get the unqualified `value_type`, independent of the the function signature.

---

Now to the other part of your question, how to write this shorter.  Well, in the case of your example one could say, that since your lambda does not capture anything it could also be replaced by a free function template.

```
template < typename T >
void cref(std::initializer_list<T> const &il) {
    /* use T and il */
}
```

or if it should work for any container

```
template < typename U >
void cref(U const &il) {
    using T = typename U::value_type;
    /* use T and il */
}
```

The clear advantage of the first case is, that you get access to `T = value_type` “for free“.  Another advantage (in my opinion) is that you will get a much clearer compiler error should you accidentally call this function with something that is not a `std::initializer_list<T>`.  You could remedy this shortcoming of the lambda by adding a `static_assert` but that would further strain the “shortness” which you initially wanted to find.

---

Lastly, if you really like the lambda style of writing functions or you have to capture something and cannot use the free function approach, you might want to consider using the **GCC extension** for template lambdas:

```
auto cref_lambda = [] <typename U> (U const &il){
    using T = typename U::value_type;
};
```

That's probably the shortest you can get.